# using real ip address for sockets in ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets

server.rb

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.open("", 8900)

m = server.accept

m.close
```

client.rb

```
require 'socket'

client = TCPSocket.open("localhost", 8900) 

client.close
```

How i can connect to my server using my real IP address.
When i change localhost with my ip address in client.rb and try to connect it gives me

```
Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
from client.rb:3:in `open'
from client.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

I tried many different ports but still not working.

Comment: How did you determine your IP address?

Comment: used whatsmyip in google

Comment: That shows your external IP address. Your router or firewall is probably blocking incoming connections. Opening / forwarding port 8900 should fix the problem.